How do I create user logins on my read replica database?
Is it possible to have different users accessing my read replica DB? Isn't this in fact a popular use case for a read replica? I want a certain limited set of credentials to have access to my primary read-write DB, and then I want a bunch of other folks to be able to have read-only access to the read replica for reporting, ad-hoc querying, etc. I don't necessarily want the two databases to have the exact same accessors.
I created a Microsoft Entra login on the server which hosts my read replica, But here's what I get when I attempt to create the user for the database access.

Msg 3906, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Failed to update database "********" because the database is read-only.

Well, of course the database is read-only, it's my read replica. But I'm not trying to write data into the database, merely set the meta-security details for who in my organization is allowed to access the read replica. This can't be done?


Is it possible to have different users accessing my read replica DB?

Yes, to an extent.

Isn't this in fact a popular use case for a read replica?

Moving reads onto readable replicas from the primary? Yes!

I want a certain limited set of credentials to have access to my primary read-write DB, and then I want a bunch of other folks to be able to have read-only access to the read replica for reporting, ad-hoc querying, etc. I don't necessarily want the two databases to have the exact same accessors.

I'm not entirely sure what is meant by "the exact same accessors" but I'm going to take it as "I don't want the same logins and users on each instance". Given that understanding, the answer is no, it's not currently possible.
You can have different access per instance, but the database itself will either need to have a user created for that login or the login needs to be sysadmin.

Well, of course the database is read-only, it's my read replica. But I'm not trying to write data into the database, merely set the meta-security details for who in my organization is allowed to access the read replica.

That metadata lives in the database, so yes you are trying to write data into the database. Users live in in the database and are tied to logins (which live in master) via their SID. If you're trying to add a login to the instance, that's fine and will work. If you're trying to add a user, it needs to be added to the primary replica and will flow through to the secondary replicas. The logins aren't required to be on each replica, the users can't be changed as discussed.

So the superset of ALL users has to be defined on the primary database?

Yes, the primary is the only writable copy of the database and adding users requires writing to the database.

And then the subset of logins has to be created on each server?

Yes. If you don't want that login to access the database on that server then don't add it. That's what you're asking to achieve in your question, I believe.

How would I even create a user on the primary database if the login for that user didn't exist on the primary server?

If it's a SQL login that will be tied to the user then use the SID option of CREATE USER. If it's a domain login then just use CREATE USER with the domain login name. The user in both cases will have the correct SID to tie them to the login.

To follow this to its conclusion, the primary DB and Server need to have the supersets of logins and users that are to be granted access to the database on any of its secondary locations?

The primary (whichever server that is at any given point in time) is the only place that users can be added. If you want a user to have access it needs to be done there. Unless using sysadmin logins, the login will need an associated user (technically you could do other things to get access without a user but that's suspect at best). Each servers doesn't need the same logins, just the logins you want on that server.
Users live inside the database, including database permissions. Logins live in master along with server level permissions. If you want to add user permissions it needs to be completed on the primary.

Can you elaborate on this: "If you're trying to add a login to the instance, that's fine and will work."?

Much as I stated, logins live in master so there is no problem adding logins on a secondary replica since nothing needs to be written to the database.

What is the purpose of a login without a corresponding database user?

There are a multitude of uses. In your case, it would allow a login with sysadmin to access the database without an associated user.

So the superset of ALL users has to be defined on the primary database? And then the subset of logins has to be created on each server? How would I even create a user on the primary database if the login for that user didn't exist on the primary server? To follow this to its conclusion, the primary DB and Server need to have the supersets of logins and users that are to be granted access to the database on any of its secondary locations? This hardly seems to be a well maintainable approach. Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Can you elaborate on this: "If you're trying to add a login to the instance, that's fine and will work."? What is the purpose of a login without a corresponding database user? Thanks!

Answered your new questions @YossiGeretz

I understand from this posting, the process of adding the user to the primary DB so that it will be defined for the read-replica. But now my question has come full circle. How do I keep that user which I want to be restricted to the read-replica from accessing the primary? This is the use case which, to my mind, must be a very popular scenario, yet there doesn't seem to be any support for this. I'm going to be spending a bunch of time and effort in creating the read-replica and these users are liable to simply jump back into the primary database unless I can restrict them from doing so.

You don't add a login on the primary for them.

But if the users are Microsoft Entra accounts, whether or not they have a corresponding SQL Server login is irrelevant. A Microsoft Entra account can access a database for which it is defined as a user, regardless of whether a login exists for it on the database server.

A user cannot authenticate to a database unless the database is contained. The login at the server level must authenticate first.

How is it then, that the following statement, with no corresponding login allows me access to the database? CREATE USER [********@hotmail.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER. This is the crux of my problem. I am finding that, after creating this user in the primary DB, which flows through to the replica, the account holder is able to login to the DB on BOTH primary and replica server, regardless of whether there is a corresponding login, there is not a corresponding login, or there is a corresponding disabled login.

It depends on how you have things setup. That's a completely different question and will require completely different investigations. @YossiGeretz

Thanks! Posted here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/338711/how-does-this-user-log-in-to-the-database-server-when-its-login-is-deactivated
